# How to break branch name for building alpha

Tags: github, github-actions, git-branch

I need to build android alpha build using `./gradlew assembleAlphaRelease -Pbuild=1234`, where `1234` is the part of my branch name.
Branch is usually named like **fix/NN-1234**, how can I get only number **1234** from branch name?

Thanks in advance, just starting to learn, so question could be very simple, but I am blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **regex** in a run command to extract the number from the branch name:

For example, something like this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [fix/NN-*]

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract branch number
        id: version
        run: |
          BRANCH=${GITHUB_REF}
          echo $BRANCH
          BUILD_NUMBER="${BRANCH//refs\/heads\/fix\/NN-/}"
          echo $BUILD_NUMBER
```

Would print on the workflow:

```
refs/heads/fix/NN-123
123
```

I tested it here:

- [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/7131490442?check_suite_focus=true)
- [workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester45.yml)

Comment: Thank you so much, I incorporated it and it works! Follow up question, for cases with different branch names, e.g. it can be `feat/NN-123` or `task/NN-123`, can I somehow add this capability to the code?

Comment: Yes. You would have to add this case to the `run` step, as well as adding the `task/NN-*` to the workflow trigger.