# Pull request triggered gha not executed for branch pattern

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the following GHA workflow trigger

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'something/**'
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      BRANCH:
        description: The branch to run the workflow from
        required: true
```

I then create a PR from branch named `something/test-001` to `master`.

However the workflow is not running.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try using this pattern `something/*`?

Comment: yes, same result

Comment: Strange, it seems similar to the pattern that was used in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72803738/how-to-break-branch-name-for-building-alpha/72816037#72816037), the only difference was `branches: [somehting/*]` with `[ ... ]`. Could be related to an github instability: https://www.githubstatus.com

Comment: Do you see any error in **Actions** tab for your workflow?